# HQL update query for entities with OneToMany relationship

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hql

Models:

```
@Entity public class Team {

      Long teamId;

      String teameName;

      @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID", nullable = false)
      private Set<Player> players;
      /**
         more code for getters and setter for all fields       
      */       
    }

    @Entity
    public class Player {

        String PlayerName,
        String address 
        /**
         *more code for getters and setter for everything       
        */
    }
```

I am trying a HQL update query which looks like which is not working:

```
"update " + Team.class.getName() + " set teameName = :teameName, players = :players where teamId = :teamId";
```

The exception I am getting is: `Missing IN or OUT parameter at index`.

So what would be the correct way to achieve the same.

Comment: Do you get any error message? This would be relevant.

Comment: You shouldn't use a query. You should just modify the managed entity, and let Hibernate save it for you.

Comment: If you have a reference from the Player to the Team in the class model, you can update that with an HQL statement. However, you don't really benefit from having an ORM when you start to write your business logic in database scripts.

Comment: @JBNizet I have some specific requirement for which I have to use query.

Comment: @J.Chomel Added exception detail in question.

Comment: Why you want save entity manually. Let hibernate do that.Do your business logic on set and just provide object to hibernate.

Comment: who is your :players parameter? Are you sure is Set?